# Unusual formatting for date and times: wish to convert to datetime objects

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a .csv file with three columns, one representing date, one time, and a third associated values. The columns are as shown:

```
date        time        value
02112017    143335      1.79
03112017    153540      0.86
04112017    164015      2.79
05112017    135150      3.50
```

After uploading the .csv file into Python and querying data types, "date" and "time" are integer values and "value" are float values.

I would like to combine the "date" and "time" columns into a single column of datetime objects, that I can then plot against "value" column to make a timeseries. As such:

```
date        time       datetime
02112017    143335     02-11-2017 14:33:35
```

I've tried to concatenate these values and then use pd.to_datetime to convert them to datetime objects, but get a series of error messages thrown up - including the message:

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 00
```

If anyone could shine a light on what I'm missing, I'd be grateful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First join columns and then use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
s = df['date'] + ' ' + df['time'].astype(str)
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(s, format='%d%m%Y %H%M%S')
print (df)
       date    time value            datetime
0  02112017  143335  1.79 2017-11-02 14:33:35
1  03112017  153540  0.86 2017-11-03 15:35:40
2  04112017  164015  2.79 2017-11-04 16:40:15
3  05112017  135150  3.50 2017-11-05 13:51:50
```

Comment: Nice one. In my case i have to replace first statement by : s = df['date'].astype(str) + ' ' + df['time'].astype(str) or s = df['date'].map(str) + ' ' + df['time'].map(str) because csv data not in str format. Anyway thx.

Comment: Thanks! I also had the same issue, that I had to include 'astype(str)' for my "date" column. But otherwise it worked. Now to work out how to plot this!